# Whats the best approach to view a file in flutter which is not defined by type

Tags: flutter, plugins, download, document, offlineapps

I am in a situation where I need to store a document which can be of any type like. pdf, Docx, excel or an image. now I don't have the option to force only one type.

The issue is what to do for an app to work for ios/android as same. should I ask the user to upload the file and store it on the server and ask them to download every time they need it? or upload a copy to server and store it locally where they can access it.

if later is the way to go as a user might need to access the document offline. so what to do for this?

any plugin to use for the same.